# Find Error When I run model in YOLOV8 custom data set from roboflow

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolov8, roboflow

when i run this command it show that error in picture

%cd {HOME}
!yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolov8m.pt data={dataset.location}/data.yaml epochs=15 imgsz=800 plots=True

how can i solve this problem
[image]

Comment: What is the content of your `data.yaml` file? It seems like there is a problem with the data path.